# Need help with regular expression to transform code

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I have an enormous list of the following items:

```
    _tags.Add(Foo.Bar,
                  new Baz(
                      ...
                      ));

        _tagNames.Add("Bar",
                  _tags[Foo.Bar]);
```

where Bar and Baz(...) vary, and _tags, _tagNames and Foo stay the same.

I want to transform to

```
    case "Bar":
        _tags.Add(Foo.Bar,
                  new Baz(
                      ...
                      ));

        _tagNames.Add("Bar",
                  _tags[Foo.Bar]);

        break;
```

I am using Visual Studio, which supports regex.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Update: VS couldn't handle 2300 instances of this regex. I got this working in Eclipse:

Search Pattern:   _tags.Add((?:.|\R)*?_tags[Foo.(.*?)]);

Replace:         case "\1":\n\0\n break;

Comment: Its not clear enoght what you want to do

Comment: Updated my answer. I tested in on vs2008 and it should work so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on VS 2008:

```
_tags\.Add\((.|\n)@_tags\[Foo\.{(.@)}\]\);
```

Whith this as replacement string:

```
case "\1":\n\0\nbreak;
```

You might have to insert some tab-characters to keep your indention (or use auto-format).

**UPDATE:**

Tested and fixed regex for usage in vs

Comment: Turns out VS can't handle regex on 1800 instances of this pattern. Can you suggest a scripting language that could process this?

Comment: I use regex with PHP and Java. Both should be able to handle many files and even large files if used properly. Unfortunately the setup ist not that quick. If you have an eclipse running or a local xampp you might be lucky.

Comment: I got this working in Eclipse:  _tags\.Add\((?:.|\R)*?_tags\[Foo\.(.*?)\]\);       case "\1":\n\0\n break;

Comment: Yeah, it did, no probs. Eclipse rocks!